# Can a 4 byte timestamp value in MongoDb ObjectId overflow?

Tags: mongodb, epoch, bson, objectid

If at some time, the epoch is `ffffffff`,  than the objectId created at this moment is something like :

```
ffffffff15580625bcb65364
```

Then, what could be the ObjectId created after 1 second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, what could be the ObjectId created after [the Unix epoch rolls over in 32 bits]?

This would depend on the specific implementation, its programming language and their handling of math calculations.

It is possible that some implementations and languages would error when they retrieve the number of seconds since the Unix epoch as a 64-bit integer (which is quite common today) and then try to use a value which exceeds 32 bits in size for ObjectId generation. If this happens the driver will cease to be able to generate ObjectIds, consequently it may be unable to insert documents without _id values being provided by the application using some other generation strategy.

In other implementations the timestamp itself may roll over to zero, at which point the ObjectId generation will succeed with a very small timestamp value.

Yet other implementations may truncate (from either most or least significant side) the timestamp to coerce it into the 32 available bits of an ObjectId.

The ObjectId value itself doesn't actually *have* to have an accurate timestamp - it is required to be unique within the collection and it is "generally increasing" but MongoDB-the-database wouldn't care if ObjectId values wrapped to around zero at some point.

Answer (score 1):

As [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) says, timestamp is represented by 4-byte.

> 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId’s creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch

4 bytes is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 values, so, that is **4,294,967,295** values.

And the date from 4,294,967,295 according to unix timestamp is: **GMT: Sunday, 7 February 2106 6:28:15**

After this date, `ObjectId` won't be able to store the timestamp.

So, can ObjectId overflow? In 85 years every new `ObjectId` created will fail because it won't be able to create the timestamp with only 4 bytes.

Comment: Yes,   problem of 2106 is dreaded.   All Linux  systems  will crash and humanity will surely perish.

Comment: adding a reference for your calculation : https://github.com/uuid6/uuid6-ietf-draft/issues/23#issuecomment-898681594